# Iam trying to make one view for add and edit in codeigniter when i try to update html elements show but when i need to use add elements hides

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to make one view for add and edit in Codeigniter when I try to update HTML elements show but when I need to use additional elements hides I know the problem is that I am using foreach what can I do to make work

```
<?php include_once 'Header.php';   ?>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
<?php if($Operation == 2){ foreach ($records as  $value) :?>

    <?php if($Operation == 1) {echo form_open_multipart('Slider_Controller/AddNewSlid');} else if($Operation == 2){echo form_open_multipart('Slider_Controller/UpdateSlid/'.$value->Slid_ID. '');       }  ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Slider Title</label>
?>  
        <input type="text" name='SlidTitle' class="form-control" value='<?php if($Operation == 2){echo $value->Title; } else { echo ""; }?>'  placeholder="Slider Title">
    </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Upload Icone</label>
    <input type="file" name='userfile'>
</div>

<div class="form-group">

    <label>Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name='SlidDescription'><?php if($Operation == 2){echo $value->Description; }else if($Operation == 1){ echo null;}?></textarea>

</div>

<div class="form-group">

    <label>Select Slide status</label>
    <select class="form-control" name='Staus'>
        <option value='0'>Select status</option>
        <option value='1' <?php if($Operation == 2){if ($value->Status == "1"){echo 'selected="selected"';}}?>>Active</option>
        <option value='2' <?php if($Operation == 2){if ($value->Status == "2"){echo 'selected="selected"';}}?>>NonActive</option>           
    </select>

</div>

<?php  endforeach; } ?>

<input type="submit" name='fffff' value='go'>                  
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset Button</button>
<?php echo  form_close();  ?>
<?php echo validation_errors('<span class="error">', '</span>'.'<br>'); ?>

</div>
<!-- /.col-lg-6 (nested) -->

<!-- /.col-lg-6 (nested) -->
</div>
<!-- /.row (nested) -->
</div>
<!-- /.panel-body -->
<?php include_once 'Footer.php';   ?>
```

Comment: Just a tip you don't need to use include to load views read this https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views

Comment: can you please add your controller code?

Answer (score 0):

your code only validates for $operation == 2, there is no block if $operation == 1.

You have written form for AddNewSlid inside if $operation == 2, which is never going to be true.

Rather, move out AddNewSlid form code out of $operation == 2

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php include_once 'Header.php';   ?>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <?php
      //$Operation = 1;
      $records = array('Slid_ID' => 2,"Title"=>"vijay", "Description" => 'bangalore india', 'Status' => 1);
      $value = json_decode(json_encode($records));// comment this line means then it work for add else for edit
//      echo "<pre>";print_r($value);die;
      ?>


      <form action="<?= 'Slider_Controller/AddNewSlid/' . (isset($value->Slid_ID) ? $value->Slid_ID : '') ?>">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Slider Title</label>
          <input type="text" name='SlidTitle' class="form-control" value="<?= isset($value->Title) ? $value->Title : "" ?>"  placeholder="Slider Title">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Upload Icone</label>
          <input type="file" name='userfile'>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

          <label>Description</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name='SlidDescription'><?= isset($value->Description) ? $value->Description : "" ?></textarea>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

          <label>Select Slide status</label>
          <select class="form-control" name='Staus'>
            <?php $status = isset($value->Status) ? $value->Status : '' ?>
            <option value=''>Select status</option>
            <option value='1' <?= ($status == "1") ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Active</option>
            <option value='2' <?= ($status == "2") ? 'selected' : '' ?>>NonActive</option>           
          </select>

        </div>

        <input type="submit" name='fffff' value='go'>                  
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset Button</button>
      </form> 
        <?php echo validation_errors('<span class="error">', '</span>' . '<br>'); ?>

    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 (nested) -->

    <!-- /.col-lg-6 (nested) -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.row (nested) -->
</div>
<!-- /.panel-body -->
<?php include_once 'Footer.php';   ?>
```

this page is for add/edit

- please pass `$value` to edit only other wise `$value`  should be empty

`